# What kind of database is this schema for, and how can I open it?

Tags: export, embedded

For sentimental reasons, I'm trying to export my text messages from an old feature phone (LG Cosmos 2, circa 2011) to a flat file (CSV or the like). I was able to successfully transfer the entire contents of the phone's file system to my computer, but the messages are locked in a database format that I do not recognize.

I believe the relevant directories and files are as follows:

```
/DB
  /SchemaFiles
    /Handset
      inboxSchema.dat
  /SysDB
    SMSInboxDB.vol
    SMSInboxDB.vol.log
    SMSInboxDB.vol.sys
```

I believe the files in `SysDB` are the actual database volume files, and cannot be interpreted as plain text. However, the `inboxSchema.dat` file *can* be read as plain text, and contains the following:

```
# SMS Inbox Schema 
schema SMSInboxSchema
VERSION 0.8//SMSIN_MSG_CHARLEN

table Inbox maxrecord = 300
{
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_INBOXINDEX,          1100,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # smsInboxIndex => Primary Key
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_INBOXID,             1101,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsInboxId 
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_MSGID,               1102,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMsgID
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_CATEGORY,            1103,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsCategory
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_SYSTEMTIME,          1104,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # smsSystemTime => Soring Key
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_MCTIME,              1105,   DATE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMCTimt
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_BINMCTIME,           1106,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsBinMCTime
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_READFLAG,            1107,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsReadflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_LOCKFLAG,            1108,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsLockflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_DUPLICATEFLAG,       1109,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsDuplicateflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_PRIORITYFLAG,        1110,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsPriorityflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_PRIVACYFLAG,         1111,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsPrivacyflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_EMSUDHPRESENT,       1112,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smssmsEMSUdhPresent
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_MSGENCODINGTYPE,     1113,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMsgEncodingType
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_NUMOFSEGMENTS,       1114,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsNumOfSegments
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_TITLEMESSAGE,        1115,   STRING(301),    INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsTitleMessage
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_NUMOFVOICEMAILS,     1116,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsNumOfVoicemails
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_EMSCTRLDATA,         1117,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsEMSCtrlData
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_EMSCONCATREFRENCE,   1118,   INT,        INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsEMSConcatRefrence
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_EMSCONCATSTATUS,     1119,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsEMSConcatStatus
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_CBADDRESS,           1120,   STRING(49), INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsAddress
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_CBADDRESSLEN,        1121,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsAddress_len
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_FRADDRESS,           1122,   STRING(49), INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # smsAddress
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_FRADDRESSLEN,        1123,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsAddress_len
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_FRINTRIMEMAIL,       1124,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsIntrimEmail
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_FRNAME,              1125,   STRING(33), INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsName
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_FRPBMATCHICON,       1126,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsPBMatchIcon
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_FRPBID,              1127,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # smsPBMatchFilePos
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_SORTKEY,             1129,   STRING(49),     INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # for name/number sorting
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_SORTTIME,            1130,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # for time sorting in desc
}
multikey Inbox
{
    NORMALVALUE: SMSIN_SORTKEY, SMSIN_SYSTEMTIME;
    NORMALVALUE: SMSIN_SORTKEY, SMSIN_SORTTIME;
}

table InboxUserData maxrecord = 6000, maxviewsize = 20
{
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_INBOXINDEX,          1100,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsInboxIndex
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_SEGINDEX,            1140,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsSegIndex
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_MSG,             1141,   BINARY(220),    INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMsgLen, smsMsg
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSIN_MSG_CHARLEN,         1142,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # userdataCharLen(before encoding)
}
multikey InboxUserData
{
    NORMALVALUE:SMSIN_INBOXINDEX, SMSIN_SEGINDEX;
}

table CMAS maxrecord = 100
{
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_INBOXINDEX,        1170,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # SMSCMASboxIndex => Primary Key
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_INBOXID,           1171,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsInboxId 
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_MSGID,         1172,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMsgID
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_CATEGORY,          1173,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsCategory
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_SYSTEMTIME,        1174,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # smsSystemTime => Soring Key
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_MCTIME,            1175,   DATE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMCTimt
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_BINMCTIME,         1176,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsBinMCTime
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_READFLAG,          1177,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsReadflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_LOCKFLAG,          1178,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsLockflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_DUPLICATEFLAG,     1179,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsDuplicateflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_PRIORITYFLAG,      1180,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsPriorityflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_PRIVACYFLAG,       1181,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsPrivacyflag
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_MSGENCODINGTYPE,       1182,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsMsgEncodingType
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_MSG_CHAR,          1183,   BINARY(220),    INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsCMASMessage
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_MSG_CHAR_LEN,      1184,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsCMASMessageLength
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_FRADDRESS,         1185,   STRING(49), INDEX_KEY_ON,   ON;     # smsAddress
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_FRADDRESSLEN,      1186,   BYTE,       INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # smsAddress_len
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_SORTKEY,           1187,   STRING(49), INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # for name/number sorting
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_SORTTIME,          1188,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # for time sorting in desc
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_SRVC_CATEGORY,     1189,   USHORT,     INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # broadcast service category
    U, SYNC_OFF, SMSCMAS_CMAS_RECORD,       1190,   ULONG,      INDEX_KEY_OFF,  ON;     # CMAE Record 01 data(Category, Urgency, ...)
}
multikey CMAS
{
    NORMALVALUE: SMSCMAS_SORTKEY, SMSCMAS_SYSTEMTIME;
    NORMALVALUE: SMSCMAS_SORTKEY, SMSCMAS_SORTTIME;
}

database SMSInboxDB;
```

What kind of RDBMS is this schema for? And, is there a publicly available tool that will let me open and export the contents of the volumes?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that might be BitPim

https://sourceforge.net/projects/bitpim/

Comment: I used Bitpim to mount and copy the filesystem from the phone, but it doesn't provide any means to actually open the database volumes.